# Encrypt and Decrypt text with RSA in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, rsa, jsencrypt

I want to encrypt text with RSA using Public.pem and private.pem

I generated these files with `openssl`

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048

openssl rsa -pubout -in private.pem -out public.pem
```

I need to encrypt the text in `javascript` (I use [this Library](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt)) only for encryption.

This text in base64 is sent to the server in C#, I use `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, but I only saw that is possible load public key with:

```
RSAParameters RSAParams = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
RSAParams.Modulus = privateKey;
RSA.ImportParameters(RSAParams);
```

But I need use my own private.pem file to decrypt my text and use it after.

How can I make this?

Comment: Unrelated: Since your question is all about the C# part, I'd remove the javascript tags. They are irrelevant.

Comment: A quick google for "C# decrypt RSA" popped up several github and other example codes, like this one: https://gist.github.com/gashupl/27e4de6bd8f021f3d61b3122e6bbf775 Can you tell, why they don't work for you?

Comment: Because, when I try Encrypt a text with RSA with my pub key in JavaScript with some library (I tried differents) I can't  decrypt with C#